# How can I get to the last level of a json nest and format the output dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I have this json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "MARVEL",
    "superheroes": "yes"
  },
  {
    "name": "Big Bang Theroy",
    "superheroes": "NO",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Sheldon",
        "superheroes": "NO"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "dragon ball",
    "superheroes": "YES",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "goku",
        "superheroes": "yes",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "gohan",
            "superheroes": "YES"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I know how to loop and go through it but I need an output like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "MARVEL",
    "answer": [
      {
        "there_are_superheroes": "YES"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Big Bang Theroy",
    "answer": [
      {
        "there_are_superheroes": "NO",
        "new_leaft": [
          {
            "name": "sheldon",
            "there_are_superheroes": "NO"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "dragon ball",
    "answer": [
      {
        "there_are_superheroes": "YES",
        "new_leaft": [
          {
            "name": "goku",
            "answer": [
              {
                "there_are_superheroes": "YES",
                "new_leaft": [
                  {
                    "name": "gohan",
                    "answer": [
                      {
                        "there_are_superheroes": "YES"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried something like this:

```
format(d) {
if (d.children) {
  d.children.forEach((d) => {
    format;
  });
}
}
format(data);
```

I don't know how to get the structure I want. I have tried to do it with `foreach`, but at one point I don't know how to dynamically access until the last `children`, this is an example but I can have `n` levels where there can be elements with more `children`. In my real project I am getting a structure from a web service, I need to structure it like this.

the attribute called `superheroes` I want it to be shown inside an array called `answer` and inside of it, `there_are_superheroes` it will have its value.

```
 "name": "MARVEL",
 "answer": [
        {
          "there_are_superheroes": "YES",  --> `there_are_superheroes` was `superheroes`,
          "new_leaft": [
                    {
 .
 .
```

and `new_leaft` is the equivalent of `children`

As I said, I know how to go through objects and arrays but in this case, I don't know how to go to the last `children nested` of each object.

Comment: You'll want to use recursion for that.

Comment: @ChrisG I also tried something like that, but with the output I need I don't know how to do it, I have tried many things but it is c

Comment: If you don't know how to recurse, at least post your code to handle the topmost layer. Your description is pretty confusing.

Comment: @user202729 Excuse me, it is complicated to explain, and my native language is not English, in the same way I put the expected output, but as I said, even with recursion, I don't know how to get the structure I want

Comment: I mean, can you write code to process only the topmost layer? If you're not very familiar with recursion at least you can do this?

Comment: @user202729 I put the code I do the recursion with, I have updated my question. but as I tell you, I don't know how to form the expected output

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do one level of recursion:

```
function format(l){
    const result = {name: l.name};
    result.answer = [{there_are_superheroes: l.superheroes}];
    result.answer[0].new_leaft = l.children;
    return result;
}
format({
      "name": "Big Bang Theroy",
      "superheroes": "NO",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Sheldon",
          "superheroes": "NO"
        }
      ]
    })

// result:

{
    "name": "Big Bang Theroy",
    "answer": [
        {
            "there_are_superheroes": "NO",
            "new_leaft": [
                {
                    "name": "Sheldon",
                    "superheroes": "NO"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If the list of possible keys is fixed, it's very simple. Otherwise use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy all the keys (or just [iterate through those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)), then modify the necessary keys.

Now you have to figure out where to put the recursion calls (hint: `l.children.map(format)`, whether the key should be named `tree` or `new_leaf(t)`, check if the field exists and handle accordingly, (See the question [In Javascript. how can I tell if a field exists inside an object? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476255/in-javascript-how-can-i-tell-if-a-field-exists-inside-an-object)), etc.

Comment: thanks for your good attitude, just inside tree I want to put my exit. I will modify that structure. I was able to reach the same level as you set, that's why I don't know how to continue

Comment: @yavg That's why you should have said that in the question...

Comment: I added some more info on how to recurse.